# memory consumption apache2.4

Tags: performance, apache, vps

I'm having problems with apache these days. I have a VPS that has 4GB of RAM and hosts a website with 50,000 hits a day. The other day I saw that my MySQL server (hosted on the same VPS) was dropped, then I saw that the system had begun to swap. When I opened the file apache2.conf saw that there was no rule for Prefork, so I decided to limit the apache processes.

Now I see that the average size of apache process with this command:

```
ps -ylC apache2 | awk '{x += $8;y += 1} END {print "Apache Memory Usage (MB): "x/1024; print "Average Proccess Size (MB): "x/((y-1)*1024)}'
```

and the result is:

```
Apache Memory Usage (MB): 3748.25
Average Proccess Size (MB): 234.265
```

I think that this average size is exaggerated, but I don't know.

The next step I have done has been to calculate the appropriate number of MaxClients with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calculate MaxClients by dividing biggest Apache thread by free memory"
if [ -e /etc/debian_version ]; then
 APACHE="apache2"
elif [ -e /etc/redhat-release ]; then
 APACHE="httpd"
fi
APACHEMEM=$(ps -aylC $APACHE |grep "$APACHE" |awk '{print $8'} |sort -n |tail -n 1)
APACHEMEM=$(expr $APACHEMEM / 1024)
SQLMEM=$(ps -aylC mysqld |grep "mysqld" |awk '{print $8'} |sort -n |tail -n 1)
SQLMEM=$(expr $SQLMEM / 1024)
echo "Stopping $APACHE to calculate the amount of free memory"
/etc/init.d/$APACHE stop &> /dev/null
TOTALFREEMEM=$(free -m |head -n 2 |tail -n 1 |awk '{free=($4); print free}')
TOTALMEM=$(free -m |head -n 2 |tail -n 1 |awk '{total=($2); print total}')
SWAP=$(free -m |head -n 4 |tail -n 1 |awk '{swap=($3); print swap}')
MAXCLIENTS=$(expr $TOTALFREEMEM / $APACHEMEM)
MINSPARESERVERS=$(expr $MAXCLIENTS / 4)
MAXSPARESERVERS=$(expr $MAXCLIENTS / 2)
echo "Starting $APACHE again"
/etc/init.d/$APACHE start &> /dev/null
echo "Total memory $TOTALMEM"
echo "Free memory $TOTALFREEMEM"
echo "Amount of virtual memory being used $SWAP"
echo "Largest Apache Thread size $APACHEMEM"
echo "Amount of memory taking up by MySQL $SQLMEM"
if [[ SWAP > TOTALMEM ]]; then
      ERR="Virtual memory is too high"
else
      ERR="Virtual memory is ok"
fi
echo "$ERR"
echo "Total Free Memory $TOTALFREEMEM"
echo "MaxClients should be around $MAXCLIENTS"
echo "MinSpareServers should be around $MINSPARESERVERS"
echo "MaxSpareServers should be around $MAXSPARESERVERS"
```

and this is the output:

```
Calculate MaxClients by dividing biggest Apache thread by free memory
Stopping apache2 to calculate the amount of free memory
Starting apache2 again
Total memory 3954
Free memory 3603
Amount of virtual memory being used 0
Largest Apache Thread size 252
Amount of memory taking up by MySQL 106
Virtual memory is ok
Total Free Memory 3603
MaxClients should be around 14
MinSpareServers should be around 3
MaxSpareServers should be around 7
```

With these parameters, apache no longer swaping, although the web has become completely inaccessible, reaching 1 minute to load the home page. In addition, the CPU usage is about 85%.

That's the complete config of Prefork:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          4
    MinSpareServers       3
    MaxSpareServers       7
    MaxClients            15
    MaxRequestsPerChild   500
</IfModule>
```

Anyone know how I could do that got it running properly? Thank's everyone!

Comment: It seems to be memory leak from your application. You can run profiler tools to identify same.

Comment: Mmmm I don't think so, few days ago the aplicaction runs normally. The App catch a lot of info per second and stores it in a DB, maybe this is the problem.